# find ".ts" but not ".d.ts"

Tags: find

I thought this would do the trick:

```
find src -type f -regextype egrep -regex '.*(?<!\.d)\.ts'
```

But it doesn't seem to be matching anything.

I think [that](https://regex101.com/r/TN9B69/1) should work, but I guess this "egrep" flavor doesn't support negative backreferences unless I didn't escape something properly.

For reference,

```
 % find src -type f
src/code-frame.d.ts # <-- I want to filter this out
src/foo.ts
src/index.ts
```

Is there another quick way to filter out `.d.ts` files from my search results?

```
 % find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git
```

Comment: Here's a wiki page describing the supported regex flavors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I don't believe `egrep` supports that syntax (your expression is a Perl compatible regular expression).  But you don't need to use regular expressions in your example, just have multiple `-name` tests and apply a `!` negation as appropriate:

```
find src -type f -name '*.ts' ! -name '*.d.ts'
```

Comment: Is the space needed? i.e. will `!-name '*.d.ts'` work?

Comment: Yes, it is required.  Try it and see for yourself.

Answer (score 29):

You can get the result you want by filtering on file names only, negating the test for files you don’t want:

```
find src -type f -name \*.ts ! -name \*.d.ts
```

Comment: What's the difference between `\*.ts` and `'*.ts'`?

Comment: They’re different ways of preventing expansion: `\*.ts` escapes the `*`, so it’s not considered as a globbing character, and `'*.ts'` single-quotes the whole expression, so none of it is expanded.

Answer (score 6):

A simple (maybe less efficient) approach can be filter out the don't-want string.

```bsh
find -name "*.ts" | egrep -v "\.d\.ts$"
```

Comment: This would fail to filter out files that happen to have names ending in `.d.ts` but that also has a newline preceding that part of the filename. It's an unlikely technicality, but Unix filenames may contain newlines.

Comment: yes you are right, however from the data posted seems that is not the case and can be a valid solution candidate

Comment: Also, such special cases (if needed, or there is security concern) could be handled with for example `find -name "*.ts" -print0 | egrep -vzZ "\.d\.ts$" | xargs -0i printf '{}\n'`. I like this answer as additional one as it gives option for more complex handlings if needed (`grep -P`, `perl -0`, etc)

Comment: So can Windows apparently.  Took me a long time to figure out why I couldn’t delete the “Icon” files that kept appearing in imported files.